# How can I expand a div (collapsible) from a menu after dropping in a separate div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to learn coding and not proficient at it. Beginner here.

I created a menu, with some div's that are draggable and collapsible and I would like them to expand as I drop into another box area (similar to widgets). I have written the code, but I am unable to make it work.

Is there a way of doing it?

HTML

```
<div id="box1" class="box1">

      <div class = "widget" draggable="true" id="widget1">
        <div class="collapsible" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">widget1<span class="close"> &times;</div>
          <div class="content">
            Choose the content... <br/>
            Place everything here <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box2" class= "notcollapsible">
    </div>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
      event.preventDefault();

      // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
      if ( event.target.className == "box2" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );

          var content = this.nextElementSibling;

      //trying to expand next </div class= "content"> but I am unable to//

          if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
              } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
          }            
      }
    
  }, false);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Awesome you started to code, welcome to the community.

You could look use CSS flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

A flex div can grow with the content placed within